# Not a valid XPath expression trying to use div aria label contains

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to locate div aria-label containing "Following" but I get the below error.

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[contains(@aria-label, 'Following' and @role='button'] because of the following error:   
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[contains(@aria-label, 'Following' and @role='button']' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Code:

```
unfollowuser = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@aria-label, 'Following' and @role='button']")))
```

Element I'm trying to locate:

```
<div aria-label="Following @AfifRah88504204" role="button" tabindex="0" class="css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-1niwhzg r-1ets6dv r-sdzlij r-1phboty r-rs99b7 r-2yi16 r-1qi8awa r-1ny4l3l r-ymttw5 r-o7ynqc r-6416eg r-lrvibr" data-testid="1354561188005347337-unfollow" style=""><div dir="auto" class="css-901oao r-1awozwy r-18jsvk2 r-6koalj r-18u37iz r-16y2uox r-37j5jr r-a023e6 r-b88u0q r-1777fci r-rjixqe r-bcqeeo r-q4m81j r-qvutc0" style=""><span class="css-901oao css-16my406 css-bfa6kz r-poiln3 r-a023e6 r-rjixqe r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0"><span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">Following</span></span></div></div>
```

After "Following" there is @AfifRah88504204 which changes as I use different links so I want to only locate the div aria-label containing the text "Following".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is it able to locate the element?

Comment: can you provide me the link and details what to do ?

Comment: No, I get the above error.

Comment: The error is in the code that I use to locate the element. It says not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Is it not a typo? I've used xpaths a while ago and can mistake, but shouldn't 'and' be applied to contains and role rules? Like `//div[contains(@aria-label, 'Following') and @role='button']`. You've missed a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Worked like a charm! @SUTerliakov

Could you answer the question so I can select the answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in given xpath, which is invalid due to missing parenthesis. The following should work:

```py
unfollowuser = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@aria-label, 'Following') and @role='button']")))
```